# Azure Data Factory: Pagination in Data Flow with Rest API Source

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a API source in an ADF DataFlow task. The API source gives me the current page and the toatl number of pages in the body of the response. I want to use that information to paginate through my API source. I'm able to paginate through it just fine outside of a DataFlow activity using the range function. The issue is that the Rest transformation in a DataFlow activity does not support the range function. I've been trying to use the AbsoluteUrl function plus an expression to do add one to the current page returned by the body but either pagination does not accept expressions or I cannot figure out the syntax

I have a url like this:

BaseURL/fabricationcodes?facets=relatedArticles:Not%20Empty&page={PageNumber}.

In this example my rest linked service URL has everything I need minus the &page=pageNumber. So I'm trying to add that part with the key/value pair function of AbsoluteUrl. The Key being &page= and the value should be currentPage +1. My desire is for it to get the first page, page 0 and then add +1 to that to formulate the next pages url. the end condition being when body.totalPages == body.currentPage

I've tried a bunch of different expression formaulations but none seem to work and debugging in a Data flow is tough b/c the logging and error messaging is poor
[What I have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMkKP.png).

Comment: can you please shhare sample response of your API?

Comment: In alternative way you can use foreach activity to do pagination

Answer (score 0):

As data flow don't support Range option or you cannot use dynamic expression to get page from API response.

To work around the issue, you can use Data Flow activity within ForEach loop using range function in dynamic expression.

First take a web activity and pass the URL of the Rest API as below Ito get the total no of Pages from API response
[image]

then take a for each activity to iterate on API like pagination give the Dynamic expression as `@range(1,activity('Web1').output.total_pages)`

[image]

I will iterate the API till the respective range in sequential manner.

create parameter with type string in source DataSource.

[image]

give that parameter as dynamic value in relative URL.

[image]

after this gave parameter value as `?page=@{item()}` to give the no coming from range to the page.

[image]

**OUTPUT:**

[image]